# Jquery .prev() unintended results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these content editable fields with a little pencil icon next to them to give the user some visual feedback. However when the user clicks on the pencil, some other element gets the focus I am applying with jquery. The desired result is the jquery should find the prev element and focus that.

html

```
 //these divs are all over the page..
  <div>
    <span class="editable" contenteditable="true">my title </span>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </div>
```

jquery

```
//focus the prev .editable match, not any of the other .editables within the dom   

$( ".fa-pencil" ).click(function() {
    $( ".fa-pencil" ).prev( ".editable" ).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the element you are clicking on.

```
$( ".fa-pencil" ).click(function() {
    $(this).prev( ".editable" ).focus();
});
```

With `$(".fa-pencil").prev( ".editable" ).focus();` you reference every element with that class and find its sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inner jquery selector using this.

$(this).prev('.editable')....

In this way, jquery will start looking for a editable span from the clicked icon. Now you are looking "document-wide"